# converting only the floats of a column to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "value": [10,10.00,"123JK",20,10-11,11.00,12.00]})
```

```
ID   value
1      10
2    10.00
3    123JK
4     20
5    10-11
6    11.00
7    12.00
```

I want to convert only the floating value to integer such that:

```
ID   value
1      10
2      10
3    123JK
4      20
5    10-11
6      11
7      12
```

I tried following code:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
df['ID'].astype(np.int64,errors='ignore')
```

But It does not convert all the floating value to integer.

Comment: Your column is a string, so iterate through the coumn instead.

Comment: The script seems wrong... aren't you interested in the "value" column, not "ID"? ID is already type int64. "value" is a mix of object types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need integers only for floats integers like `10.0` use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        x = pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore')
        if int(x) == x:
            return int(x)
        else:
            return x
    except:
        return x


df['value'] = df['value'].apply(f)
print (df)
   ID  value
0   1     10
1   2     10
2   3  123JK
3   4     20
4   5  10-11
5   6     11
6   7     12
```

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming that the `value` column be text, you could just do a regex replacement here:

```py
df["value"] = df["value"].str.replace(r'^(\d+)\.\d+$', r'\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `pd.to_numeric` with `fillna`:

```
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['value'])
```

This will convert to numerical `dtype`s and replace non-numeric data to `NaN`. Then I fill the `NaN`s with the original column with strings, this will keep the numerical data numeric.

Comment: @jezrael Not reproducible for me, I tested and no floats.

Comment: maybe my pandas version. OK.

Comment: @jezrael I use `pandas 1.1.3`

Comment: A bit old, hmmmm

Comment: @jezrael Or you could try: `pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['value']).astype('Int8')`.

Comment: Do you try it? For me failed.